# Loading fonts and images with webpacker

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker, react-on-rails

I'm trying to simply load assets (fonts/images) into a Rails project using Webpacker. It's proven to be hilariously more difficult than it should be.

I'm using React on Rails 11.0.4, Rails 5.1.6, and Webpacker 3.5.3.

I've tried creating custom loader files to append to the webpack configuration, as referenced [here](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/webpack.md).

```
// file.js

module.exports = {
  test: /\.(ttf|eot|otf)$/,
  use: {
    loader: "file-loader",
    options: {
      name: "fonts/[name].[ext]",
    }
  }
}

// environment.js

const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const file = require('./file')

environment.loaders.prepend('file', file)

module.exports = environment
```

And I've tried literally all 4 options outlined [here](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/assets.md).

I've tried using the asset pipeline, but that doesn't seem to work anymore.

I've never in all my years been so close to tears for something so incredibly simple. Shouldn't this be simple?? How am I the only one having so much trouble with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mb i help you

```
{
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|eot|otf|ttf|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../app/assets'),
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            outputPath: 'fonts/',
            useRelativePath: false
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg(eg)?|gif|ico)$/,
        exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../app/assets'),
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            outputPath: 'images/',
            useRelativePath: false
          }
        }
      },
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm convulsing with joy.